# ERROR: 'insight-dashboard-erneuerung-settings' is not a known element when implementing lazy loading

Tags: angular, angularjs, webpack, lazy-loading, single-page-application

I'm trying to set up lazy loading for the Dashboard-module in my Angular project, and I'm encountering an error:

'insight-dashboard' is not a known element:

If 'insight-dashboard' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
If 'insight-dashboard' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

The 'insight-dashboard' looks in the dashboard.component.ts like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'insight-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.scss']
})
```

As far as I understand, some parts from the DashboardModule are being used in other components (like MainWrapperComponent, SideNavLeftComponent) and cannot be identified due to lazy loading. These components (MainWrapperComponent or SideNavLeftComponent) need to be declared in the AppModule because they provide general functionality not only for dashboard and must be available throughout the application.

Here is the part from MainWrapperComponent.component.html:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="actView==='dashboard'">

  <insight-dashboard>

    <div class="ev-toolbar-theme-container">
      <button mat-icon-button matTooltip="Optionen" (click)="openRightSidenav('dashboard-options')">
        <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>

  </insight-dashboard>
</ng-container>
```

There are a lot of dependencies between Components, but I would like to know, if it is really complex to implement the Lazy Loading in this Angular-project.

Answer (score 0):

In order to prepare the `DashboardModule` for being lazy loaded you need to make sure that all its components are only used by this module. So if `insight-dashboard` is used in `MainWrapperComponent` you should extract it from the `DashboardModule` and declare it globally. Consider using shared modules for that ( https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules ). As soon as you complete such refactoring - it's not complex to turn your `DashboardModule` into a lazy loaded module.